# LM324n weird output when used as buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using an LM324n quad-core op-amp. I have connected it between +24 V and GND. One of its op amps is used as a buffer. When I pass the buffer a negative voltage, I get it inverted at the output although I expected it to be zero. Is this weird response somehow logical or expected?

Unfortunately I had some issues with Windows lately and I have no other schematic but for this handwritten one.[image] MOTOR VELOCITY input can become both positive and negative and that's where the issue is!

Comment: Schematic? Picture of the implemented circuit?

Comment: Kind of schematic added

Comment: This is real. I *think* Nat Semi documented its use as a full wave rectifier in one of their Floobydust articles ... anyone have that databook handy?

Comment: Olin and The Photon have the correct answers, but this is the first time I've heard of a quad op-amp described as quad core, LOL.

Comment: LOL that was a typo, but I'll leave it for the sake of the laugh!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is called *phase inversion*.

It happens in certain op-amps when you exceed the input common mode range limits of the op-amp (for example, when the input voltage is below the most-negative supply voltage).

It's explained at the circuit level in a TI [presentation](ftp://ftp.ti.com/pub/linear_apps/SMA-Kassel/Understanding%20Op%20Amp%20Limitations.ppt) I found (warning: Powerpoint link), and also in an EE Times [article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1231129).

Notice the input common mode minimum voltage for your op-amp is equal to the most negative supply voltage, so you should not use a 0 V VEE with this op-amp if you will have negative inputs. An easy solution in your case might be to use the op-amp with split supplies to handle the velocity input.

Comment: But since the negative input voltage is out of spec I should avoid it anyway right?

Comment: In the two datasheets I checked (On Semi and TI), the specs are written assuming VEE = GND. If VEE = -15 V, input common mode range should go down near -15 V. The chip itself really has no idea what "0 V" is except what is attached to it's VEE pin.

Answer (score 5):

You need to actually **read** the datasheet:

[image]

Note that a negative input voltage is out of spec.  When you violate a spec, there are no longer any guarantees what the part might do.  So yes, there is nothing unexpected about it inverting the signal onto the output, or doing anything else that might appear strange.  When you don't follow the rules, you can't expect it to follow the rules either.